# Install node.js youtube iframe player

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, youtube

I'm currently trying to install the following module: https://github.com/miguelmoraleda/youtube-iframe-player

I have installed "youtube-iframe-player" via npm as well as its dependency "require-sdk", but when I try to run the following code, I always get a "ReferenceError: window is not defined" error.

```
var youtube = require('youtube-iframe-player');

youtube.init(function() {
    console.log('API Loaded');

    var youtubePlayer = youtube.createPlayer('container', {
        width: '720',
        height: '405',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 1 },
        events: {
            'onReady': playerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });

    function playerReady(event) {
        youtubePlayer.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log('Player State Changed: ', event);
    }
});
```

How can I open the script in a webserver?

Any help would be really much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same problem now.